# Time Series Forecasting with multiple input, single output that has multiple values for each time step

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to understand if possible to generate a time series forecasting program that is able to deal with multiple values for each time step. Examples like this [tensor flow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#the_weather_dataset) show time series forecasting with a single set of data for each time step but is it possible for the timestep to also have multiple sets of values?